# Label in axis x does not show correct data (using javascript)

Tags: javascript, jsp

I am trying to show the bar chart in JSP file, using javascript.
In the bar chart, there is axis x to show the id patient.

This is my code in JSP file:

```
<c:forEach items="${attachment1}" var="a">
    <div class="id_Patient">${a.id_patient}</div>
</c:forEach>
```

And this is my javascript code when I try to show in the bar chart:

```
for(var i=0;i<blobLength;i++) {
    getAge(blob[i]);
    console.log("id patient : " + Id_patient2[i]);
    dataPointAge.push({
        label: Id_patient2[i]
    });
    chart.render();
}
```

As you can see, before I push the label: `Id_patient2[i]` into `dataPointAge` list, I tried to show the content inside `Id_patient2[i]`.
This is the result on the console (that is show correct data):

[image: result id patient on the console]

But when I show the bar chart on the web page, it showed the inappropriate result. Like the picture below:

[image: result in axis x]

How to solve this, so that, I can show the correct data into the axis-x (label) on the bar chart?

Comment: Looks like the `x-label` is set to `default`. What library are you using?

Comment: can you copy paste your entire code? Difficult to guess from your function